# Правильное использование async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Из прочитанного про async/await, я понял что эта конструкция должна упростить код, избавить разработчиков от лишних коллбэков. Я запустил такой пример:

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('asyncawait/async');
var await = require('asyncawait/await');

function getQuote() {
  var quote;

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request('http://ron-swanson-quotes.herokuapp.com/v2/quotes', function(error, response, body) {
      quote = body;
      resolve(quote);
    });
  });
}

var main = async (()=>{
  var quote = await(getQuote());
  console.log(quote);
});


main();

console.log('Ron once said,');
```

В консоли вижу следующее:

```
Ron once said,
["Great job, everyone..."]
```

Это говорит о том, что `main()` срабатывает после `console.log('Ron once said,')`.

Но в чем суть тогда, если один-черт нужно передавать коллбэк в `main()` чтобы сначала получить результат запроса, а потом что-то с ним делать?

Как добиться того, чтобы в данном примере сначала сработал `main()` а потом `console.log()`?

Comment: например добавить await при вызове main

Comment: ну так вы await не делаете для main()

Comment: Я не совсем уверен, но это какой-то неправильный костыльный async/await, по-моему лучше дождаться нормальной поддержки браузерами

Comment: @andreymal, почему неправильный? И при чём тут браузеры?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что вместо нормальных async/await я вижу тут [полифилл-костыль](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asyncawait) на этих самых несчастных коллбэках (async/await здесь - функции, а не операторы). Окей, браузеры ни при чём, нода в вопросе не упоминается, а теги я не глянул) Но это ничего не меняет - нативной поддержки async/await в ноде [всё равно нет](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/).

Comment: @Qwertiy кстати, по той же причине, что "async/await здесь - функции, а не операторы", ваш ответ не работает и, формально, неверен :)

Comment: @andreymal поддержки браузерами, насмешил =) открой вики https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich см. мой второй коммент

Comment: Тут есть пример  https://jsfiddle.net/bx5c7xqe/1/

Comment: @andreymal, тега изначально не было. Но node.js'ный код http-запроса узнаётся замечательно. Скобки в ответ добавил.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, там babel.

Comment: @Qwertiy, babel -- временное решение, пока не будет поддержки ES7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`async` определяет, что функция является *асинхронной* и позволяет использовать внутри нее оператор `await`, который *приостанавливает* выполнение функции, на время получения результата. Обращаю ваше внимание, что конструкцию `await` можно использовать не везде, а только внутри асинхронных функций.

До определения `async/await` подобно поведение достигалось использованием генераторов в комплекте с библиотеками, вроде [`co`](https://github.com/tj/co). Я уже детально расписывал этот подход в [одном из своих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527799/182771).

---

Теперь несколько слов о вашем конкретном примере. Основная цель, насколько я могу видеть, в *псевдо-синхронном* выполнении связки:

```
main();
console.log('Ron once said,');
```

Казалось бы, функция `main` определена как асинхронная и этот блок должен выполняться последовательно. Однако вы упускаете один очень важный момент: определение функции асинхронной не делает ее вызов псевдо-синхронным *автоматически*. Вам нужно в *явном* виде дождаться результата выполнения `main`.

Для этого нужно просто обернуть *весь* ваш код в [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)-выражение, использующее асинхронную функцию и дождаться результата выполнения `main`:

```
let getData = () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('Great job, everyone...');
        }, 500);
    });
};

(async () => {
    let main = async ()=> {
        console.log(await getData());
    };

    await main();
    console.log('Ron once said,');
})();
```

Этот пример выведет:

> Great job, everyone...
>   Ron once said,

А вот и работающий [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/hf7pmw3p/) на JSFiddle.

**Замечание:**

Код выше я написал на чистом JS, без использования библиотеки-полифила [`asyncawait`](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait). Если вы хотите использовать эту библиотеку, то вместо ключевых слов `async`/`await` вам нужно в явном виде вызывать функции этой библиотеки.

В качестве альтернативы, я бы предложил использовать [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), превращающий ES 6/7 код в то, что уже сегодня можно запустить в большинстве браузеров.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> main();
> ```

Если надо ждать, то это надо указать:

```
await (main());
```

Comment: Таким образом я получаю ошибку `await main(); SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. для этого нужно как-то запустить ноду в режиме компилирования через babel?

Comment: @sanu0074, если посмотрите в вашем случае `await` похоже функция, по этому должно быть как-то так `await( main());`

Comment: @sanu0074, добавил скобки.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это так же вызывает ошибку: `Error: await functions, yield functions, and value-returning suspendable functions may only be called from inside a suspendable function.`

Comment: @Qwertiy, ключевое слово `await` можно использовать **только** в функции, помеченной как `async`.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ну значит не выйдет. Можно было бы всё обернуть в функцию, но ожидания всё равно не оправдаются, как только кто-то сделает require этого модуля...

Comment: `require` не должен приводить к _выполнению_ чего бы то ни было на прямую. А возвращать асинхронные функции можно.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, но ведь в данной реализации код вызывается непосредственно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, но ведь в данной реализации ничего не сказано про `require` этого кода.