# Как выполнить sql запрос используя async/await в node 7?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Допустим я использую node-mysql из npm для выполнения sql-запросов. С появлением node 7 и поддержки ней async/await, хотелось бы понять, как можно применить это для выполнения sql запросов? Задача в целом написать класс-обертку для node-mysql, чтобы потом можно было делать нечто вроде:

```
let data = new MySqlWrapper().select(query);
```

ну и в итоге в `data` мы имеем результат выполнения запроса.

Подскажите как можно реализовать это на данном примере:

```
(async () => {
            let getData = async ()=> {
                db.query(`select * from users`,null,(err,data) =>{
                    console.log('ok');
                    return data;
                });
            };

            var res = await getData();
            //нужно чтобы в res пришли данные запроса
})();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конструкции `async/await` отлично работают не только с асинхронными функциями, но и с *Обещаниями* (*Promises*). Например, код

```
let select = function(query) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {resolve(`${query}s`)}, 1000);
    });
};

async function run() {
    let foos = await select('foo');
    let bars = await select('bar');

    console.log(`${foos} + ${bars}`);
}

run();
```

выведет сообщение `foos + bars` через две секунды.

Эта маленькая хитрость позволит вам решить вашу проблему "малой кровью". Вы можете использовать одну из существующих библиотек, чтобы заставить ваши методы возвращать *Обещания*. Приведу пример того, это можно сделать используя [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html):

```
let bluebird = require('bluebird'),
    asyncWrapper = (f, ctx) => bluebird.promisify(f, {context: ctx});

let mysql = new MySql();
let data = await asyncWrapper(mysql.select, mysql)(query);
```

При желании, вы можете написать класс, содержащий в себе новый, асинхронный API. Но эта задача тривиальна и я оставлю ее для вас :)

Comment: В вашем 1-м примере, если допустить что после `run();` в самом конце будет какой-то код, то этот код не будет выполняться пока не отработает `run` (2 секунды)?

Comment: @sanu0074, нет, но этого и не должно происходить. Конструкция `await` работает только внутри асинхронных функций (с маркером `async`). Поэтому, если вам нужно выполнить что-то строго подряд, помещайте эти команды в в `run` и снабжайте их вызовы маркером `await`

Comment: @sanu0074 мы же с вами уже обсуждали `async/await` [вот тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/529177/182771).

Comment: я прочитал все, так и не пойму как заставить работать эту конструкцию, я пример в вопросе привел, можете подсказать?

Comment: @sanu0074 Перепишите весь этот ужас внутри стрелочной функции так, чтобы он возвращал промис. Пример того, как с минимальным трудозатратами сконвертировать функцию, принимающую колбэк в функцию возвращающую промис я привел в ответе.

Comment: спасибо) с промисом заработало