# Сохранение результата запроса к mongodb в переменную

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Очень нужна ваша помощь. Вроде бы простой вопрос, но не могу понять как сохранить результат запроса к базе в переменную, используя mongoose. Предположим есть база данных test. Нужно запросить все записи из этой базы и сохранить в виде массива в переменной data.
Пробовал так:

```
var data = Test.find({}, (err,results) => {
  if(err) throw(err);
  console.log(results);
  return results;
});
console.log(data);
```

console.log(results) внутри функции печатает идельный массив. console.log(data) вне функции печатает огромный массив в котором есть масса инфрормации о структуре коллекции, описание запроса, но нет данных из БД.
Пробовал так:

```
function getResult() {
  Test.find({}, (err,result) => {
    if(err) throw(err);
    return result;
  })
};
var data = getResult();
console.log(data);
```

Результат - undefiened.
Помогите пожалуйста. Если объясните суть проблемы то буду вдвойне благодарен.

Comment: суть проблемы - вы ожидаете, что код выполняется сверху вниз, последовательно, то есть синхронно. а JS выполняется асинхронно. познакомьтесь с Promise и [async/await](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529291/287469) и [колбеками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554291/287469).

Comment: Да, я уже понял что суть в асинхронности. Несколько раз читал материалы по этой теме, но пока не догоняю сути. Буду признателен если предложите конкретное решение для этого вопроса.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Суть проблемы - вы ожидаете, что код выполняется сверху вниз, последовательно, то есть синхронно. А JS выполняется асинхронно. Чтобы получить последовательное выполнение асинхронного, нужно использовать async/await совместно с Promise и колбеками.

Это - теория. А теперь - практика. Ниже рабочий код, все разъяснения - в комментариях.

```
"use strinct";

const
  mongodb = require("mongodb"),
  assert = require("assert"),
  MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient,
  config = {
    mongo: {
      uri: "mongodb://mongo:27017",
      db: "test_db",
    }
  };

class App {

  constructor(config) {
    this.config = config;

    // конструктор будет возвращать Promise, который можно "then()" и "catch()"
    return new Promise(async (appResolve, appReject) => {

      try {
        // ждем подключение к Монге, оно также асинхронное
        await this.connectMongo();
        // инициализация (не обязательно)
        await this.initMongo();
        appResolve(this);
      } catch (err) {
        appReject(err);
      }

    });
  }

  // эта часть взята с моего проекта
  // тут создаем коллекцию с уникальным полем email
  // разумеется, в Монге специально коллекции создавать не нужно, они создаются при первой вставке в них,
  // но тут добавляется уникальный индекс email
  async initMongo() {
    let collection = this.mongo.collection("mails");
    await collection.createIndex( { "email": 1 }, { unique: true } );

    // для примера добавляем один элемент
    // replaceOne создает ИЛИ перезаписывает существующую запись,
    // это я сделал для возможности повторного запуска скрипта без ошибок
    // если использовать insertOne, то при втором запуске выскочит ошибка
    // "duplicate key error collection"
    let email = "foo@bar.tld";
    await collection.replaceOne( { email: email }, { email: email, blocked: true }, { upsert: true } );
  }

  // асинхронное подключение, тут колбек подключения к Монге завернут в Promise,
  // при подключении выполняется `resolve();` который яваскрипт ждет в строчке `await this.connectMongo();`
  async connectMongo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MongoClient.connect(this.config.mongo.uri, {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          keepAlive: 1,
          connectTimeoutMS: 5000
        }, (err, db) => {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        this.mongo = db.db(this.config.mongo.db);
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  // а вот и "проблемная" функция, она асинхронная
  async getResult(email) {
    let collection = this.mongo.collection("mails");
    return await collection.findOne({email: email.trim().toLowerCase()});
  }

}

let api = new App(config);
api.then(async (api) => {
  // тут вызывается асинхронная функция, и яваскрипт "ждет" на этой строчке
  let data = await api.getResult("foo@bar.tld");
  // после завершения асинхронной функции данные в переменной уже будут
  console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
  // тут обработка ошибок
  console.log("API fatal error:", err);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

**UPD**

Как я понял, используется express. Тогда код можно написать так:

```
// я поменял POST => GET для демонстрации
api.get('/test', async (req,res) => {
  // тут замените на свой клиент, я думаю это Resource
  let mongo = this.mongo;

  let collection = mongo.collection("mails");
  let data = await collection.findOne();
  // данные будут отправлены в ответе сервера
  res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Ключевое тут - `async (req,res)` и использование внутри `await`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ. Загнал Ваш код в js и запустил. В результате выдает замечательный `{ _id: 5f2235292064b70922defa5c, email: 'foo@bar.tld', blocked: true }`. Но это же опять внутри функции api! Как мне использовать этот результат ниже? К примеру если я хочу собрать новый массив, и включить туда полученный документ и затем сохранить его в mongo? Я добавил свой код с описанием, внизу Вашего ответа.

Comment: @tumanoff см **UPD**.

Comment: Заработало!!! Спасибо огромное! Надо бы разобраться с асинхронными операциями.

Answer (score 3):

```
async function getResult() {
    const data = await Test.find({});
    console.log(data);
}
```

---

> UPDATE

если Вы хотите вынести получения данных из `mongoose` в отдельную функцию (в чем я не особо вижу смысл), то попробуйте так:

```
// функция для получения данных с базы
const getResult = async () => await Test.find({});

// вызвать функцию и получить данные, но получать эти данные можно только внутри async функциях
const data = await getResult();
```

Comment: Пробую запустить функцию: `let result = getResult()` и в результате получаю `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: @tumanoff, всё верно. вариант с `let result = getResult()` не будет работать, потому что функция `getResult` рассчитана на то, чтобы получать данные из `mongoose` только внутри этой функции.

Comment: Во-первых спасибо Вам за ответы. Надеюсь в итоге пойму всю глубину глубин. То есть чтобы получить результат от `await getResult()` мне нужно завернуть это в другую `async function`, я правильно понимаю? Но опять таки, результат будет доступен только внутри этой функции. Наверное я неправильно описал вопрос. Итак есть функция, которая делает запрос к БД, получает какие то данные внутри себя и потом нужно чтобы эти данные сохранились в переменную за пределами функции. Чтобы потом впоследствии можно было использовать эту переменную где то дальше в коде.

Comment: @tumanoff, да,чтобы получить результат от `await getResult()`, Вы должны вызвать эту функцию внутри асинхронной функции (`async function`). но это не обязательно, так как `getResult()` будет возвращать `Promise` и вы можете обработать его не с помощью `await`, а через `.then()` и тогда Вам не обязательно получать результат от `getResult()` внутри `async` функции

Answer (score 1):

Потому что операция асинхронная.

Думаю, можно так:

```js
let data;
function getResult() {
  Test.find({}, (err,result) => {
    if(err) throw(err);
    data = result;
  })
};
```

Comment: Пробую `console.log(data)` после функции, все равно пишет что `undefined` :(